Plotting 2 sets of data onto one graph on Python
This is my python code used to plot 2 sets of code on the same set of axis. I need the simulated code and original code on the same graph so that I can see how well they fit.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits


file_path = 'GalCat_extra_lean.fits'
hdul = fits.open(file_path)
data = hdul[1].data


halo_mass = data['mass_halo']
nsat = data['N_sat']

hdul.close()

# Define the halo mass and the mean number of satellites
selected_halo_mass = 1e12  # Selected halo mass in solar masses
mean_nsat = 20  # Mean number of satellites

# Generate simulated measurements using a Poisson sampler
np.random.seed(42)  # for reproducibility
simulated_nsat = np.random.poisson(mean_nsat, size=len(halo_mass)).astype(float)  # Convert to float
mask = halo_mass != selected_halo_mass
simulated_nsat[mask] = np.nan  # Set values to NaN where halo mass is not equal to the selected halo mass

# Plot the scatter plot with original data
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(halo_mass, nsat, color='blue', alpha=0.5, label='Original Data', s=0.2)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Halo Mass [$M_☉$]')
plt.ylabel('Number of Satellites ($N_{sat}$)')
plt.title('Number of Satellites vs. Halo Mass (log-log)')
plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="--")

# Plot the simulated data as a scatter plot with a different marker style or color
plt.scatter(halo_mass, simulated_nsat, color='red', alpha=0.5, label='Simulated Data', s=0.2, marker='x')

plt.legend()
plt.show()

my plot
i can't get my simulated data to show up on my plot
How do i do it?

Have you tried to increase the width of the points of the simulated graph? It seems to be hidden by the large quantity of points of the experimental data. Did you tried to plot the simulated before experimental?
What is the range of simulated_nsat (min and max)?
